# module 'cv2' has no 'imread' member pylint(no-member)

Tags: python, opencv, vscode, cv2

Buenas alguien podría decirme como solucionar este problema con `python`, estoy trabajando con VS Code.

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Son errores del _linter_ de VSCode, lo cual no implica necesariamente errores en tu aplicación ¿Si la ejecutas te funciona? Es posible que el linter no tenga acceso al `import cv2` y de ahí los problemas. ¿Te has asegurado de elegir el intérprete python adecuado, si por ejemplo tienes varios instalados o varios entornos virtuales?

Comment: Como señala abufalia es un error del linter, quizas este post te ayude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612169/pylint-not-recognizing-cv2-members

Comment: ya lo solucione gracias

Comment: @AgustinCoronel si ya solucionaste tu problema seria genial que publicas tu solución como respuesta para que les ayuden a otros que tengan el mismo problema, y marcarla como correcta en 2 dias.

Answer (score 1):

Hice 2 cosas

1:
Buscar el archivo en el vscode del proyecto con Ctrl + SHIFT + P y buscar "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" ingresar en ese archivo y agregar la siguiente linea de codigo "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generate-members"], guardar los cambios.

2:
descargar un archivo de nombre "frozen_east_text_detection.pb" y pegarlo dentro de la carpeta del proyecto.

Con eso funciono

Comment: funciona perfecto! gracias!